# Let X,Y be connected topological spaces. Show $X\times Y\setminus (x_0,y_0)$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

> Let X,Y be connected topological spaces that are not singleton. Show $X\times Y\setminus (x_0,y_0)$ is connected.

I managed to prove if $(x_0,y_0)$ is a closed set but havn't if it is not given, but my teacher said it is true.

Thank you,

Comment: You mean $y_0$ instead of $y+0$?. Also, $X\times Y$ looks better, try `\times` for the product symbol.

Comment: Is $(x_0, y_0)$ just any point in $X \times Y$? Any other assumptions on the point or on the spaces?

Comment: I have edited to increase readability. The example $X=\mathbb R$, $Y=\{0\}$, and $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$ shows that you need additional assumptions.

Comment: I dont know that {$x_0$} is closed in X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general it is not true. As an example take $X = \{x_0\}$ and $Y = \mathbb  R$ with $y_0 = 0$. Then
$$X \times Y \setminus \{(x_0,y_0)\} = \{x_0\} \times (\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}) \approx \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} .$$
However, if we assume that both $X,Y$ have at least two points, then we can prove it as follows.

All sets $X_y = X \times \{y\}$ with $y \in Y$ and $Y_x = \{x\} \times Y$ with $x \in X$ are connected. Pick $x_1 \in X \setminus \{x_0\}$ and $y_1 \in X \setminus \{y_0\}$. Then
$$Z = Y_{x_1} \cup \bigcup_{y \ne y_0} X_y$$
is connected because all $X_y$ intersect $Y_{x_1}$. Note that $X_{y_1} \subset Z$. We conclude
$$X \times Y \setminus \{(x_0,y_0)\} = Z \cup \bigcup_{x \ne x_0} Y_x$$
is connected because all $Y_x$ intersect $X_{y_1}$ and therefore intersect $Z$.